# In react-beautiful-dnd i want to resize icon on every div after drop. i want to resize my div

Tags: reactjs, next.js, resize, react-beautiful-dnd

How can I implement post-drop resizing functionality using react-beautiful-dnd in React functional components? I want to display a resize icon on each dropped div to enable users to dynamically adjust the height and width after dropping an element. The goal is to seamlessly integrate resizing capabilities with the drag-and-drop functionality, ensuring a fluid and intuitive user experience.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.